# What is "roundtripping" in the context of Pandas?

Tags: pandas

The [documentation for `pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) mentions something called 'roundtripping', under the description of the `index_col` parameter.

> Missing values will be forward filled to allow **roundtripping** with `to_excel` for `merged_cells=True`.

I have never heard of this term before, and if I search for a definition, I can find one only in the context of finance. I have seen it referred to in the context of merging dataframes in Pandas, but I have not found a definition.

For context, this is the complete description of the `index_col` parameter:

> **index_col : *int, list of int, default None***
>
> Column (0-indexed) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. Pass
> None if there is no such column. If a list is passed, those columns
> will be combined into a `MultiIndex`. If a subset of data is selected
> with `usecols`, index_col is based on the subset.
>
> Missing values will be forward filled to allow roundtripping with
> `to_excel` for `merged_cells=True`. To avoid forward filling the
> missing values use `set_index` after reading the data instead of
> `index_col`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general idea of the meaning of `roundtripping`, have a look at the answers to this [`post`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119440/what-does-it-mean-by-the-round-trip-problem) on SE. Applied to your example, "allow roundtripping" is used to mean something like this:

> facilitate an easy back-and-forth between the data in an Excel file
> and the same data in a `df`. I.e. while maintaining the intended
> structure throughout.

**Example round trip**

The usefulness of this idea is perhaps best seen if we start with a somewhat complex `df` with both index and columns as named `MultiIndices` (for the constructor, see [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4,4), 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],[1,2]],
                                                     names=['col_0','col_1']), 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[1,2]], 
                                                   names=['idx_0','idx_1']))

print(df)

col_0               A                   B          
col_1               1         2         1         2
idx_0 idx_1                                        
0     1      0.952749  0.447125  0.846409  0.699479
      2      0.297437  0.813798  0.396506  0.881103
1     1      0.581273  0.881735  0.692532  0.725254
      2      0.501324  0.956084  0.643990  0.423855
```

If we now use [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) with the default for `merge_cells` (i.e. `True`) to write this data to an Excel file, we will end up with data as follows:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Result:

[image: data Excel]

Aesthetics aside, the *structure* here is very clear, and indeed, *the same* as the structure in our `df`. Take notice of the merged cells especially.

Now, let's suppose we want to retrieve this data again from the Excel file at some later point, and we use [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with *default* parameters. Problematically, we will end up with a complete mess:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
print(df)

  Unnamed: 0  col_0         A  Unnamed: 3         B  Unnamed: 5
0        NaN  col_1  1.000000    2.000000  1.000000    2.000000
1      idx_0  idx_1       NaN         NaN       NaN         NaN
2          0      1  0.952749    0.447125  0.846409    0.699479
3        NaN      2  0.297437    0.813798  0.396506    0.881103
4          1      1  0.581273    0.881735  0.692532    0.725254
5        NaN      2  0.501324    0.956084  0.643990    0.423855
```

Getting this data "back into shape" would be quite time-consuming. To avoid such a hassle, we can rely on the parameters `index_col` and `header` inside `pd.read_excel`:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1])

print(df2)
col_0               A                   B          
col_1               1         2         1         2
idx_0 idx_1                                        
0     1      0.952749  0.447125  0.846409  0.699479
      2      0.297437  0.813798  0.396506  0.881103
1     1      0.581273  0.881735  0.692532  0.725254
      2      0.501324  0.956084  0.643990  0.423855

# check for equality
df.equals(df2)
# True
```

As you can see, we have made a "round trip" here, and `index_col` and `header` allow for it to have been smooth sailing!

---

Two final notes:

1. (minor) The [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for `pd.read_excel` contain a typo in the `index_col` section: it should read `merge_cells=True`, not `merged_cells=True`.
2. The `header` section is missing a similar comment (or a reference to the comment at `index_col`). This is somewhat confusing. As we saw above, the two behave exactly the same (for present purposes, at least).